# Font shape undefined when using OpenType font and mathdesign

Tags: fonts, luatex, mathdesign

I'm trying to use Adobe Utopia fonts for text and `mathdesign`'s `utopia` font for math. But with this sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Utopia Std}
% \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Also doesn't work
\begin{document}
hello $world$
\end{document}
```

I get the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/mdput/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 186.
```

even though the output looks fine. I searched a bit and found out that `lmr` is the Latin Modern font, but it doesn't appear anywhere in the document (as far as I could see). Using other fonts (for example `TeX Gyre Pagella` also doesn't work), and even if I don't use another font at all:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
hello $world$
\end{document}
```

How to properly get rid of that warning?

Comment: `\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}` (before `\usepackage{mathdesign}`) removes the warning - but you can also just leave it.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, that helps with the second code, but as soon as I add `fontspec` (which I need), the warning returns... You say "just leave it": is that warning harmless? Where is it trying to use `lmr`?

Comment: All right, I found an actual solution, but it’s a really ugly hack.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to suppress the error message (thanks, @egreg, for pointing out how the first idea didn’t work), but it’s an **extremely** ugly hack.  I would honestly just ignore it as harmless.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utopia, euro=false]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{substitutefont} % Ugly hack to suppress warning.
\substitutefont{TU}{mdput}{lmr} % Ugly hack to suppress warning.
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Lingua Franca}[NFSSFamily=mdput]

\begin{document}
hello $world$
\end{document}
```

Another workaround is to load `unicode-math` with STIX Two for the math symbols and Utopia (or a clone) for the letters.  Here, I use the free Lingua Franca.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmainfont{Lingua Franca}[Scale = 1.0] % Or Utopia Std
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{Lingua Franca Regular}[range=up,
  Script=Default, script-features={}, sscript-features={}]
\setmathfont{Lingua Franca Italic}[range=it,
  Script=Default, script-features={}, sscript-features={}]
\setmathfont{Lingua Franca Bold}[range=bfup,
  Script=Default, script-features={}, sscript-features={}]
\setmathfont{Lingua Franca Bold Italic}[range=bfit,
  Script=Default, script-features={}, sscript-features={}]

\begin{document}

Hello, \(\mathit{world}\)!

\end{document}
```

I added a few extra options to suppress harmless warning messages.  I had a hunch you’d want me to.

Comment: Not really. The warning is still there.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for checking. That’s odd. Without having the package to examine, my next idea would be [substitutefont](https://ctan.org/pkg/substitutefont?lang=en). If that works, I’ll edit my answer, and if it doesn’t, I might as well delete it.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks for your answer! However I still get the warning with `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Utopia Std}[NFSSFamily = mdput]
\begin{document}
hello $world$
\end{document}`. Am I doing something wrong? I already tried changing the order of the packages

Comment: @LaTeXer No, you aren’t doing anything wrong. The top user of this site, all-time, tried and it didn’t work for him either. it looks like my guess about what’s causing the problem is not correct.

Comment: @Davislor Okay, thank you! I hope someone knows what is happening. Thank you for your time!!

Comment: @LaTeXer I’ll take a closer look when I get the chance.